# How to create and use a database in java

Tags: java, database

I have developed a Java GUI application which uses a MS Access as database. But, after my research I came to know that it can only store 2 GB data. Now I am planning replace it with some other database.

```
Which is the free and easy to use sql database?
```

Comment: There are tons of dabases : relational/object, persistent/in-memory etc. You should explain your need more in detail. Which type of application are you planning to do ? Do you need other systems to connect to this db?

Comment: And even if OP does explain his requirements, then still answer will be primarily opinion-based. I think that place for such question with detailed specification of requirements should be posted at dba.stackexchange.com/‎

Comment: the application will be used by multiple users(upto 10), bascially a  file/connection to place in a network folder and distribute the jar file to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java connectivity with MySQL DB:

```
http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html
Step By Step Explanation: http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/MysqlConnect.shtml
```

Apache Derby:

```
It is Relational Database similar to MySQl developed by Apache.
```

Tomcat Server

```
As name says, it is a server, which listens to request on particular port, process dynamic request and respond back to client.
```

Answer (score 1):

download mysql and use it. you can download from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

I would think of Apache Derby as a database used mainly for testing purposes, and I think it can only be accessed by a Java application.

Therefore, I recommend MySQL as a free and easy to use SQL database.
IMO, MS Access is not a proper database, it's a toy database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MySql database**.You can download it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).You will need a **JDBC driver** to connect to MySql which you can get [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/). If you are using **Java 7 then JDBC 4** will already be present. Just put the driver jar file in the class path. It will automatically be picker up. No need to do need to do `Class.forName("someDriver");`

Answer (score 1):

### Tomcat server is a web server to run java

You can use Mysql database or, sql server database,....

To use mysql you can read at here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html